# How to erase path area from canvas (Android)

Tags: android, canvas, path, transparency, erase

I need to crop corners on `ImageView`. Not to round them but erase triangles from each corner.

Seems like the only way to do that is to override `onDraw` method and erase these areas from canvas using `Path`. The problem is I have not solid color background, so I need ERASE these areas but not to fill them with some color.

I use following code for that:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(20, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, 20);
    path.close();

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

But the corner makes black but not transparent. Could you help me? Or probably you know better solution for my task. Here is how it looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In order to draw with a transparent color you must use `Paint` `setXfermode` which will only work if you set a bitmap to your canvas. If you follow the steps below you should get the desired result.

1. Create a canvas and set its bitmap.

   ```
   mCanvas = new Canvas();
   mBitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(scrw, scrh, Config.ARGB_8888);
   mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
   ```
2. When you want to erase something you just need to use setXfermode.

   ```
   if (isErasing)
      mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
   else
      mPaint.setXfermode(null);
   ```
3. Now you should be able draw with a transparent color using:

   `mCanvas.drawPath(yourpath, mPaint);`

Comment: draws with transparent color, but the path drawn is black, any workaround for this??

Comment: I can still see some "ghosting" of the deleted object.

Answer (score 2):

You can clip your canvas object:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final Path path = new Path();
    final int count = canvas.save();

    path.moveTo(0, 20);
    path.lineTo(20, 0);
    path.lineTo(getWidth(), 0);
    path.lineTo(getWidth(), getHeight());
    path.lineTo(0, getHeight());
    path.close();

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restoreToCount(count);
}
```

Please note `Canvas.clipPath` doesn't work on Android 3.0 or above with enabled hardware acceleration .

Comment: didn't work for me. I still have white rectangle without any corners

Comment: try to disable hardware acceleration

Comment: i tried to disable it manually in AndroidManifest.xml, but it didn't help

Answer (score -1):

use this Line

```
 paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
```

instead of this

```
 paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

Comment: I tried it, but it makes nothing. I don't have event black triangle. Whole area is white.